# Contextual filter based on node field

Tags: 8, views

I have previously made contextual filters for views that took a URL parameter and then filtered for related content and they worked great.

I now wish to make a view, that for a given node, lists all content that shares specific taxonomy terms from a specific vocabulary which the node is tagged with.

This should be easy but for whatever reason I am finding this ridiculously difficult. I seem to be able to either show all content or no content but not just the related content...

My general strategy has been to make a relationship to the taxonomy term on the node. Then create contextual filter in the taxonomy 'name'. Is this wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify...you want to show related nodes based on the taxonomy terms used by a node and show this block in the node's page?

Comment: I want to show it on the page strictly speaking, rather than the node (If I understand the difference)